# How to define the number of "Recent Posts" displayed in the Wordpress sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to limited the recent posts to 3 or 5. Where can I define the number of displayed   recent posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your Wordpress administration console go to "Appearance->Widgets"
2. Locate the "Recent Posts" widget in the relevant section on the right hand side
3. Expand it to view it's configuration
4. Change the "Number of Posts to Show" value to what you want and click "Save"